# Need help for Assignment! API usage for the first time on Ionic

Tags: javascript, java, angular, ionic-framework

So i'm using https://github.com/surhud004/Foodish to reference as the api, all i wanted to do is get the random image to appear on screen.

So i'm actually not sure how or why to do it, and need someone to correct me where i'm wrong or teach me my mistakes, as i'm relatively new on implementing api

i have created a food.service , so in my food.service.ts , my code will be

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FoodService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


    getAll() { // Calls when app loads - to display all countries
      return this.http.get("https://foodish-api.herokuapp.com/api");
      }
}
```

And my app.module.ts , i have imported

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    HttpClient,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

So i'm trying to implement first without creating the button on home page
so my home.page.ts

```
export class HomePage {

  ngOnInit(){
    this.loadData();
} 

  
  results: any = [];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private foodService : FoodService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) 
  {
    this.foodService.getAll().subscribe((data) => {this.results = data});
    console.log(this.results)
  }

  loadData() {    
    this.http.get("https://foodish-api.herokuapp.com/api").subscribe(
     data=>{
       console.log(data);
       this.results = data;

     }, err=>{
       console.log(err);
     }
   );
 }
}
```

and my home.page.html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
  <ion-title>
     Food
  </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>
 <ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-item button *ngFor="let result of results.images" >

    <p>{{ result.image }}</p>
  </ion-item>
 </ion-content>
```

[However im not sure why i cant retrieve the image to show, for example , click the image to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffGKO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foodservice should be:

```js
//IN THE FOOD SERVICE

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FoodService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


    getRandomImage() { // this link just return 1 object with 1 image
      return this.http.get("https://foodish-api.herokuapp.com/api");
      }
}
```

Then in home.page.ts

```js
export class HomePage {
  randomImage: string = ''; // since you are just using 1 image you can use an string instead of an array
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private foodService : FoodService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) 
  {
    //add data type "any" to eliminate the error: "Property 'image' does not exist on type Object
    this.foodService.getAll().subscribe((data:any) => {
      console.log(data)
      // the data arrives with the image link in a property called image so you should do this
      this.randomImage = data.image
     });
  }
}
```

Finally in the home.page.html

```html
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
  <ion-title>
     Food
  </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>
 <ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-item >
    // display the image from the component property randomImage
    <img [src]="randomImage">
  </ion-item>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for replying. I have follow your code however i have face another issue when i run with ionic serve

Comment: it states "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: I just edited the response, please try adding type ''any like 'data:any' as shown above in the home.page.ts document

Comment: Hey kind sir, it finally worked, thanks , it got me riled for quite some time. Have a nice day